# Вернуть ответ клиенту из после RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Есть сервер, который принимает запрос от клиента и отправляет в RabbitMQ, есть слушатель, который получает сообщения из очереди, обрабатывает его и должен обратно вернуть клиенту.Вопрос в том, как вернуть сообщение именно определенному клиенту? Т.е. у нас прерывается связь сервера и клиента, и только потом нужно вернуть ответ клиенту. Может как-то сохранять ip адрес клиента и когда все готово, возвращать на ip адрес клиента?

Comment: А как он(клиент) будет принимать ответ, через какой канал связи?

Comment: Эта реализация должна выполняться на уровне ПО - клиент шлет запрос, сервер обрабатывает и отправляет нужные данные. Смысл сохранять IP клиента? Он ничего не даст, большая часть находится за NAT-ом, и просто внешний запрос от сервера отбросит на уровне сети.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, может возможно клиента сделать подписчиком? Чтобы это асинхронно работало

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, проблема в том что, сервер, который принимаем запрос от клиента, добавляет сообщение в очередь и сервер который получает сообщение из очереди и шлет обратно клиенту это две разные программы

Comment: Ответа не было про канал связи, так что говорю про тот который знаю. 

Можете реализовать SSE/WebSockets через Javascript, куда клиент будет подписан при заходе на страницу. На сервере связываете RMQ и то, что будет в SSE/WebSockets транслировать сообщения.